Interaction as main effect in lme4 vs. nlme
Let's say I am trying to see if there are speed differences among different types of cars (e.g., jeep, SUV, truck, sports car). I also want to see whether the car store (A, B, C, D, E) has an effect on this. I don't have a specific hypothesis about the car stores, but I assume that certain stores tend to sell certain types of cars (e.g., SUVs at Store A and trucks at Store B).
So, I tried to fit a linear mixed effect model with lme4 and nlme.
I have a question about the difference between these two models:
nlme:
m1 <- lme(speed ~ car_type + car_store + car_type:car_store, 
          data = data1, random = ~ 1 | car_owner, method = "ML")

lme4 equivalent is:
m2 <- lmer(speed ~ car_type * car_store + (1 | car_owner), 
           data = data1, REML = FALSE)

Now, my question is, can I have interaction as the main effect in nlme like this:
m3 <- lme(speed ~ car_type + car_type:car_store, data = data1, 
          random = ~ 1 | car_owner, method = "ML")

So far, I can't find the equivalent of m3 in lme4. Can anyone help me understand why?
Also, ideally, I think I can achieve my purpose with m3. But is there anything else that I should consider? like perhaps it's better to use lme4 and car_store as main/fixed effect as well?

This is more about understanding how R handles main effects and interactions rather than about mixed models. In principle, the syntax with lmer() for the fixed effects will be the same as in lme(), e.g., lmer(speed ~ car_type + car_type:car_store + (1 | car_owner), data = data1).

@DimitrisRizopoulos Thanks a lot. But, here it means the interaction is a fixed effect right? Theoritical (stat) wise, can I have a suggestion if I should keep car_store as individual fixed effect or not?

There should be no difference between lme4 and nlme regarding the specification of the fixed effects. As mentioned by Dimitris Rizopoulos in a comment to the question, there is nothing specific to mixed models here.
I agree that your models m1 and m2 indeed have the same fixed effects.

Now, my question is, can I have interaction as the main effect in nlme like this:


m3 <- lme(speed ~ car_type + car_type:car_store, data = data1, random = ~ 1 | car_owner, method = "ML")


Yes, you do that, but it is not (usually) a good idea. Models that include an interaction, but exclude one or both main effects, have been discussed here many times, for example:
Including the interaction but not the main effects in a model
Unless you have a very good reason, I suggest your model's fixed effects should be:
car_type + car_store + car_type:car_store

or just:
car_type * car_store

which is shorthand for the same thing.

Thanks a lot for this and the reference.
